# Do react testUtilities rendered components need to be unmounted after each test

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I am using react-addons-test-utils with teaspoon and jest and I mount the component to be tested for each test using render or shallowRender:

```
TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Component />)
```

or

```
$(<Component />).render()
$(<Component />).shallowRender()
```

My question is do I have to unmount manually every component after each it()? If I don't will this cause memory leaks?